# Stochastic Comparabilty

Tags: probability

I have ran into a paper where the author speaks of finding the variance for the AUC (Area Under the ROC curve) for two continuous variables X and Y, which are ***stochastically comparable*** .

Does anybody have an idea what does ***stochastically comparable*** mean?

Comment: I guess it means that there is *stochastic ordering*

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate a little more? It intuitively seems to me that every set of values can be ordered, what would you mean by 'no stochastic ordering' ?

Comment: Have you read article on wiki about it?

Comment: Yes I have, I know what stochastic dominance is. In fact this sentence from the Wikipedia entry on stochastic ordering states: 'These are usually partial orders, so that one random variable A may be neither stochastically greater than, less than, nor equal to another random variable B .' - This may be the very thing I'm missing?

Comment: it's better you to find some literature about it. Unfortunatly I've read only russian books about it, but I guess there should be english one.